# Rethrow UncaughtExceptionHandler Exception after Logging It

Tags: android, eclipse, exception

In my Application class I am trying to catch a force close before it happens, so I can log it and then rethrow it so the android can handle it. I do this since some users do not report force closes.

I am developing in eclipse, and eclipse is not allowing me to rethrow the exception. It shows an error saying "Unhandled exception type Throwable: Surround with try/catch". How can I rethrow the exception?

```
public class MainApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
    super.onCreate();

    try
    {
        //Log exception before app force closes
        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                AnalyticsUtils.getInstance(MainApplication.this).trackEvent(
                        "Errors",                       // Category
                        "MainActivity",                 // Action
                        "Force Close: "+ex.toString(),  // Label
                        0);                             // Value
                AnalyticsUtils.getInstance(MainApplication.this).dispatch();

                Toast.makeText(MainApplication.this, "Snap! Something broke. Please report the Force Close so I can fix it.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                //rethrow the Exception so user can report it
                //throw ex; //<-- **eclipse is showing an error to surround with try/catch**
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apologies, not an Android expert - but looks like you can't throw ex because your method signature "void uncaughtException(Thread, Throwable)" doesn't declare that it "throws" anything.

Assuming you're overriding an API interface and (a) can't modify this signature and (b) don't want to because you'd be throwing it out of context, could you instead use a decorator pattern and basically subclass the default UncaughtExceptionHandler implementation to log your message and then let it carry on processing as usual?

Edit: untested, but this might look a bit like:

```
    final UncaughtExceptionHandler subclass = Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            // your code 
            AnalyticsUtils.getInstance(MainApplication.this).trackEvent(
                    "Errors",                       // Category
                    "MainActivity",                 // Action
                    "Force Close: "+ex.toString(),  // Label
                    0);                             // Value
            AnalyticsUtils.getInstance(MainApplication.this).dispatch();
            Toast.makeText(MainApplication.this, "Snap! Something broke. Please report the Force Close so I can fix it.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // carry on with prior flow
            subclass.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hmm I think you're right. I'm not familiar with the Decorator Pattern, could you show some code to show me how I can do this?

Comment: Yup that worked! Thanks Capn Sparrow. (Note: The toast does not show.)

Comment: Bit late here but as I've just used Capn Sparrow's solution I should point out the toast doesn't show because there is now .show() at the end of the makeText call. This gets me so often.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this question only now, I'm not sure if any of the above answers were correct when posted, but they're not now. What you want nowadays is to create a new class that implements `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` and in the constructor, save `Thread.getCurrentUncaughtExceptionHandler()` to a field, and you call *its* `uncaughtException(Thread, Throwable)` at the end of *your* `uncaughtException(Thread, Throwable)` method. Then you call `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()` from whatever code instantiates your class, often `MainApplication.onCreate`.

So the full code would look something like:

```java
//MainApplication.java
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler cueh = new CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(cueh);
    }
}

//CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler.java
class CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler oldHandler;

    CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        oldHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        AnalyticsUtils.getInstance(MainApplication.this).trackEvent(
                "Errors",                       // Category
                "MainActivity",                 // Action
                "Force Close: "+ex.toString(),  // Label
                0);                             // Value
        AnalyticsUtils.getInstance(MainApplication.this).dispatch();
        if (oldHandler != null) {
            oldHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        else {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also store the original default uncaught exception handler somewhere else for restoration later (or add a `getOldHandler()` method) if for whatever reason you decide you don't want your code to run anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want, however you can add a `finally` clause that will run after either a successful `try` or a handled `catch`:

```
try {
    //your code
} catch (Exception e) {
    //print stack trace
} finally {
    //Log
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, as I'd like a "catch all" that will log any exception before it force closes my app. I use try/catches but just in case something gets uncaught.

Answer (score 0):

I think following code should work. Executing handler code using a new Thread allows application to show alert/toast and perform other operations.

Also, you may try invoking `System.exit(0)` just before exiting `run()`. This relaunches the last activity.

I checked this on both *Ginger Bread* as well as *Jelly Bean*.

```
final UncaughtExceptionHandler subclass = Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();  
                    // your code 
                    AnalyticsUtils.getInstance(MainApplication.this).trackEvent(
                            "Errors",                       // Category
                            "MainActivity",                 // Action
                            "Force Close: "+ex.toString(),  // Label
                            0);                             // Value
                    AnalyticsUtils.getInstance(MainApplication.this).dispatch();
                    Toast.makeText(MainApplication.this, "Snap! Something broke. Please report the Force Close so I can fix it.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    Looper.loop();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```